# Android Studio Kotlin ListView - Entries - Static Cells

Tags: android, listview, kotlin

I am coming from programming in Swift/Xcode and they have a tableview where I can create static cells that I can edit and populate within storyboard which in Android/Kotlin is just the layout XML file.

I am having trouble finding info on if I can create the cells manually within the XML file instead of programming them and manually populating them with content like buttons and text fields. If I wanted to program them I would of course use a RecyclerView instead.

I am aiming to create a registration view with different types of registration inputs in a list view.

For example, the registration view will have a map for user to take location details and use them for the registration as well as basic text fields and buttons.

Comment: "I am aiming to create a registration view with different types of registration inputs in a list view" -- that does not sound like a typical use of `ListView`. It feels more like a `ConstraintLayout`, perhaps wrapped in a `ScrollView` to enable the entire form to be scrolled.

Comment: Solved my learning curve for Android today :) thanks